# Velocity : Find mathing strings and store them in an array

Tags: string, velocity

I have a text and I want to extract some string basing on a regular expression pattern:

```
<div>This is a text</div><div>  </div><div>here is another text</div>
```

How can I store all the occurences between `<div>` and `</div>` in an array avoiding the empty/space strings ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to parse content from an html/xml document. Velocity would be useful for taking an array of strings and putting them in div tags... not the other way around.

[HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) is a useful tool which formats html into xml (i.e. includes closing p tags and things). You can then easily get the content of the div tags using xpath.

Here's some untested code that should get you started:

```
try {
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    TagNode node = cleaner.clean(htmlString);
    Object[] elements = node.evaluateXPath("//div");
    for(Object element : elements){
        System.out.println(((TagNode) element).getText().toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getLogger().error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
} catch (XPatherException e) {
    Logger.getLogger().error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}
```